# Getting single result from a query with anonymous types in Linq To Sql

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, anonymous-types

I have a query with single result. The result is an anonymouse type. How can I use access the type so I don't have to use query.Single() every time?

This is my query:

```
var result = from row in db.Table 
select new { CustomName = row.RowName };
```

This is how I use it right now:

```
string name = result.Single().CustomName;
```

Of course my real code has a lot more properties and for every property I have to call .Single() every time. Is there an easier way to access CustomName here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried assigning the `Single` result to a variable?

```
var singleResult = result.Single();
string name = singleResult.CustomName;
// etc...
```

Furthermore, each time you call `Single()` it will execute the query. You *should* grab the value once and use it wherever you need. As long as you use `var` you should be fine, you just can't return that anonymous type from a method.

Answer (score 4):

You can say

```
var result = (from row in db.Table
              select new { CustomName = row.RowName }).Single();

string name = result.CustomName;
// etc.
```

But probably the best way is to encapsulate your result into a bonafide non-anonymous class. Then you can say

```
MyClass result = (from row in db.Table
                  select new MyClass() { CustomName = row.RowName }).Single();

string name = result.CustomName;
// etc.
```

Here you would have, for example,

```
class MyClass {
    public string CustomName { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
var result = (from row in db.Table 
select new { CustomName = row.RowName }).Single();
```

Then you can access your property with

```
var foo = result.CustomName; // etc
```